# Powershell how to close the opened video file?

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems

How to close the opened file in windows machine?

I have a video file in my `C:\downloads\playme.mp4`
Now I have opened PowerShell window and type this command

```
Invoke-Item C:\downloads\playme.mp4
```

file has opened successfully , but how to close it?

Comment: You will have to kill the video player it opened with. Did it open with Windows media player? VLC? `Stop-Process -Name "Windows Media Player"` or whatever the program it is playing in is

Comment: Thank you , but it is failing with an error ..file has opened and playing in media player but not able to close it..       Cannot find a process with the name "Windows Media Player". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.
At line:6 char:1
+ Stop-Process -Name "Windows Media Player"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Windows Media Player:String) [Stop-Process], ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopProcessCommand

Comment: it worked with stop-process -.name "wmplayer"

Comment: Thank you for your sharing!